# Launching Openstack instance with Bootable VM

Tags: python-3.x, shell, openstack, qemu, openstack-nova

I am facing problem while booting my vm with this error message please someone help me out`===>>MP-BIOS bug: 8254` timer not connected to **IO-APIC**.
what should i do or what I'm missing?
Help me out.

1) my hypervisor is "qemu" and 2) vncserver_proxyclient_address=cloud.openstack.lan 3)Hypervisor Config==> 1)vncserver_proxyclient_address=cloud.openstack.lan 2)osapi_compute_listen=0.0.0.0 3)osapi_compute_listen_port=8774 4)compute_manager=nova.compute.manager.ComputeManager 5)volume_api_class=nova.volume.cinder.API These are my NOVA and hypervisor configuration..

BootingImg==>CentOS7x86_64Minimal1611.iso OpenstackConfigration Bare metal service OpenStack Compute OpenStack dashboard Database service for OpenStack OpenStack Identity OpenStack Image service OpenStack Networking

Hypervisor setting: 1)Hostname => cloud.openstack.lan 2) Type = QEMU 3) VCPU =1 4)RAM=2.5GB 5) RAM (total) = 3GB 6) Local Storage (used) = 20GB 7)Local Storage (total) = 21GB 8) Instance = 1 Actually i am using Openstack-mitaka

Distribution is= •  PackStack - scripted puppet runs

Comment: There could be issue with hypervisor settings or booting images itself. Please add details of hypervisor you are using, your openstack configuration, openstack distribution, booting image etc.

Comment: Please add info to question itself.

Comment: hello, Sanket can u help me with some suggestions or solutions that i can move on. Please..

Answer (score 0):

So you can find multiple references to problem like yours all over the google:

1. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=698842
2. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707820

What is strange that all these problems are like at lest 3 years old. Is this an option that you have some old system running on hypervisor? 
Some people claim 'noacpi' kernel option added to guest kernel may help, worth to try.

Comment: yes on top of Openstack.. and that VM is not booting successfully while booting VM i am getting this error message and my OS is "CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.ISO" with Nova.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel command line option `no_timer_check` helped me with this (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5 guest). But this I suspect the OpenStack install was not solid. Need it only in one cluster. See

- https://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/fedora-cloud/msg03961.html